# WHMCS Invalid Csrf Protection Token Error

Tags: csrf, whmcs

I am using whmcs for a long time but 2 days ago my licence was suspended due to unknown reason, now its unsuspended but i was unable to login, it shows "INVALID CSRF PROTECTION TOKEN". i have tried my best but not resolved .

Answer (score 3):

I realized this was related to [another issue with sessions](https://help.whmcs.com/m/troubleshooting/l/678268-troubleshooting-login-problems) which I was having. That article states that the issue comes up for 1 of 2 reasons:

> - The configured session tmp path not being writeable
> - The configured session tmp path being full

After doing `phpinfo()`, I realised my `session.save_path` was pointing to a non-existent directory. Had to edit my `php.ini` and set its value to `/tmp`.

Issue fixed.

Comment: It is very important to figure out the reason why it happened. Your answer is best suited and more reasonable. Thumbs up!

Comment: I had the same issue but was discovered by the admin user never logs in, the admin page just refreshes and asks for credentials again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [WHMCS forum post](https://whmcs.community/topic/243345-invalid-csrf-protection-token-version-6/?do=findComment&comment=1173753), they suggest to disable Session IP Check.

Setup > General Settings > Security tab

Or from phpmyadmin, run this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `tblconfiguration` SET `value` = 'on' WHERE `setting` = 'DisableSessionIPCheck'
```

Comment: But issue is that I am using whmcs 7.4, to open setup tab it need to provide password.

Comment: Create a test.php file and add phpinfo(); into it and see the session path, and make sure that path is writable. Refer to the answer by @Cedric Ipkiss.

Comment: WEHRE should be WHERE